# Sum of divisor powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

A given number is divisible by 2, 3, and 5, and has altogether 2013 divisors. The
smallest such number is $2^N \cdot 3^M \cdot 5^p$ where $N + M + P=$?

I would $N + M + P = 2012$ because by a combinatoric principle, $2^{11}$ has $11 + 1 = 12$ divisors. Here it will be the same then. But

$2^n \cdot 3^m \cdot 5^p$ has the number of divisors: $(n+1)(m+1)(p+1)$

So here too,

$(n+1)(m+1)(p+1) = 2013$

Just an idea?

Comment: Quite right.  Find the factors of 2013, and decide which one goes with $n$ and which with $m$.

Comment: HINT: $2013=3.11.61$

Comment: So sum is 2 + 10 + 60 = 72

Comment: yes i think, is it not?

Comment: $N+M+P=2012$ is wrong.

$(N+1)(M+1)(P+1)=2013 = 3 \times 11 \times 61$

Comment: @TahirImanov, I meant, Sum is 2 + 10 + 62 = 72 in the following comment?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ndroock1, is the sum $72$?

Answer (score 0):

A number that meets the criteria is for example $1701971548138242677145600 = 5^2 3^{10} 2^{60} $ it is divisible by $2, 3$ and $5$. The divisor count is $(2+1)(10+1)(60+1)=2013$ and, now answering OP's question: the sum of the exponents in the prime factorization is 72.